# How can I get below answer based on given tables with data? I have done some steps but not able to get the answer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Tables:

TABLE1: PROGRAM

| Prgm_name | Company | People |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X CO., Y CO. | JOHN |
| B | M CO., N CO., O CO. | KRISH, BIKRAM, TOM |

TABLE2: COMPANY

| Company_name | Program | People |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X CO. | A | JOHN |
| Y CO. | A |  |
| M CO. | B |  |
| N CO. | B | KRISH, TOM |
| N CO. | B |  |

TABLE3: PEOPLE

| Full_name | Company | Program |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN | X CO. | A |
| BIKRAM |  | B |
| KRISH | N CO. | B |
| TOM | N CO. | B |
| LYNN | N CO. |  |

```
create table Program
(
    Prgm_name varchar(225),
    Company varchar(500),
    People varchar(500)
)

create table Companies
(
    Company_name varchar(255),
    Program varchar(500),
    People varchar(500)
)

create table People
(
    Full_name varchar(225),
    Company varchar(500),
    program varchar(500)
)

insert into program values ('A', 'X CO., Y CO.', 'JOHN')
insert into program values ('B', 'M CO., N CO., O CO.', 'KRISH, BIKRAM, TOM')

insert into Companies values ('X CO.','A','JOHN')
insert into Companies values ('Y CO.','A','')
insert into Companies values ('M CO.','B','')
insert into Companies values ('N CO.','B','KRISH, TOM')
insert into Companies values ('O CO.','B','')

insert into People values ('JOHN','X CO.','A')
insert into People values ('BIKRAM','','B')
insert into People values ('KRISH','N CO.','B')
insert into People values ('TOM','N CO.','B')
insert into People values ('LYNN','N CO.','')

SELECT * FROM Program
SELECT * FROM Companies
SELECT * FROM people
```

EXPECTED RESULT: Based on the above 3 tables I want the normalized PROGRAM table like the below:

| Prgm_name | Company | People |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X CO. | JOHN |
| A | Y CO. |  |
| B | N CO. | KRISH |
| B |  | BIKRAM |
| B | N CO. | TOM |
| B | M CO. |  |
| B | O CO. |  |

To get this result I tried to write some script but still not getting the answer. The script is as follows:

```
select * 
into #program 
from
    (select 
         a.PRGM_NAME as PRGM_NAME_P, a.COMPANY AS COMPANY_P, 
         a.PEOPLE AS PEOPLE_P, c.Full_name AS FULL_NAME_PP,
         c.Company AS COMPANY_PP, c.program AS PROGRAM_PP 
     from 
         (select distinct b.PRGM_NAME, x.COMPANY, Y.PEOPLE
          from 
              (select PRGM_NAME, COMPANY, PEOPLE from Program) b
          cross apply
              (select trim(value) from string_split(b.COMPANY, ',')) x (COMPANY) 
          cross apply 
              (select trim(value) from string_split(b.PEOPLE, ',')) Y (PEOPLE))a
     left join
         people c on a.Prgm_name = c.program AND A.COMPANY = C.Company) d


SELECT
    PRGM_NAME_P, COMPANY_P AS COMPANY_P_Y, PEOPLE_P, 
    FULL_NAME_PP, COMPANY_PP, PROGRAM_PP,
    CASE
        WHEN COMPANY_P <> '' AND COMPANY_PP = '' THEN FULL_NAME_PP
        WHEN COMPANY_P <> COMPANY_PP THEN ''
        ELSE FULL_NAME_PP
    END FULL_NAME_Y,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PRGM_NAME_P, PEOPLE_P 
                        ORDER BY COMPANY_PP DESC ) AS RANK1
FROM 
    #program
```

I am not able to do more than this. it would be a great help if anyone guide me.

Comment: Please make your title meaningful to the problem... as it is it doesn't help at all.

Comment: And if you format your code as code it is much easier to read.

Comment: And its very hard to read your sample data with all the blank rows.

Comment: Upon first read it seems like you have the same three data items represented in three different ways in three different tables. Without analysing too much I expect there is a lot of ambiguity in the data.

Comment: The primary issue here seems to be lack of normalization: store *one* item per column, not multiple, and normalize out into separate linkiing tables. And each value should have a single source of truth in *one* table, and use foreign keys to link tables up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can get the desired results with this:

```
SELECT c.Program AS Prgm_Name, c.Company_name AS Companmy, LTRIM(p.value) As People
FROM Companies c 
CROSS APPLY string_split(c.People, ',') p
UNION
SELECT p.program AS Prgm_Name, p.Company, 
p.Full_name AS People
FROM People p
WHERE p.Company = ''
```

You may find this more generally applicable.  The first half of the `UNION` simply splits the People in the Companies table into separate rows, keeping Program and Company as is.  The second half adds in those People not associated with a Company.

Note to use ´string_split´ you need Compatibility Level of at least 130 (SQL Server 2016 or higher).

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan. let me sink this with my original data.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific case, this query returns that dataset. But the information is so ambiguous I expect this will not be sufficient for other cases.

Note I'm not even using the program table

```
SELECT COALESCE(C.Program, P.Program) Program, C.Company_name, P.Full_name
FROM Companies C
full join people P
on C.Company_name = P.Company 
and C.Program = P.program
where not (COALESCE(C.Program, P.Program) = '' AND C.Company_name IS NULL)
order by COALESCE(C.Program, P.Program), C.Company_name
```

Comment: Thank you, Nick. this code also helped me to get answers but still, I need to look at it with my original data. I want to put your answer also as an answer but I think only one can be tick marked as an answer.

Comment: You can see in the answers how ambiguous this data is - the answer uses different tables for the same output